# ASP.NET MVC showing a waiting page whilst waiting for Async Operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've pulled the code back to the basics here but what I would like to do is call a view to show the user we are waiting, then call and a task which for example purposes waits 5 seconds once this is completed I then want to call another view which shows the user the task has completed see some example code below with some comments

```
public class Test : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Show the User they are Waiting by returning a view with a label telling them
        return View("Waiting");

        // Then I want to call BeginTask and once its async operation is completed
        // Once beginTask is completed I want to show a different view telling the user the task is completed
    }

    public IActionResult Waiting()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task BeginTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }

    public IActionResult Completed()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`async` and `await` do not change the HTTP protocol; see the "Asynchronous Code Is Not a Silver Bullet" section of my [Introduction to Async/Await on ASP.NET article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#asynchronous-code-is-not-a-silver-bullet). You have one request and then one response (e.g., the view).

If you want to *change* the view after it has been sent to the browser, then the browser itself will have to communicate with the server to get the updated page, e.g., by polling or by WebSockets/SignalR. To quote the article:

> If you needed SignalR or AJAX or UpdatePanel before async/await, you’ll still need SignalR or AJAX or UpdatePanel after async/await.

The exact mechanisms to do this vary based on your front-end technology.